# Find the optimal ordering of elements

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting

I have a list of logos (up to 4 color) that need to be printed. Each logo requires a setup time to mix paints needed for that logo. If I can sort the data so that two logos that use the same colors are back to back, then we will not have to mix as many colors saving money and time. Paints have a limited life span once mixed.

I am looking at a dataset like this...

```
Red | (Other Color)
Red | Black
(Other Color) | Black
```

It needs to end up in that order. That is the only order that will allow for 1 red to me made and 1 black. I've tried a few things like assigning a value to each common color, but no matter what, I can't seem to get it ordered correctly.

---

I used the following SQL procedure that someone wrote based on the TSP problem. (http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=172154)

Using the following test data I received the correct output

```
delete from routes
delete from cities
insert into cities values ('Black|Red')
insert into cities values ('Red')
insert into cities values ('Blue')
insert into cities values ('Black')
insert into cities values ('Blue|Red')

-- Numeric Value is Colors not Matching

insert into routes values ('Black|Red', 'Red', 3)
insert into routes values ('Black|Red', 'Black', 3)
insert into routes values ('Red', 'Black', 4)
insert into routes values ('Blue|Red', 'Red', 3)
insert into routes values ('Blue|Red', 'Black', 4)
insert into routes values ('Blue', 'Red', 4)
insert into routes values ('Blue', 'Black|Red', 4)
insert into routes values ('Blue', 'Black', 4)
insert into routes values ('Blue', 'Blue|Red', 3)

exec getTSPRoute 'Black'

Results:
Black->Black|Red->Red->Blue|Red->Blue->Black
```

The only issue is running back to the original "city" (Black returned for both the start and the end) and I have to select a "start city." If the wrong one is selected I don't end up with the most optimized route.

Comment: Isn't vice-versa order OK too?

Comment: How many logos do you consider in practice? 10, 100? 10,000?

Comment: You say up to four colors per logo, how many total colors can there be across all logos?  (there are algorithms for which this is very important).

Comment: Why is it irrelevant in this example that (Other Color) has to be made twice?

Comment: I was using Other Color to represent some other non-matching color

Comment: A max of 20 logos to sort though. Each logo will have a max of four colors, but all pantone colors are available, so there may be no matches.

Comment: If you need to mix two colors, is that time-equivalent to mixing one color? Can new colors be mixed in parallel to printing -- does ordering matter for (Red, Green) and (Red, Green, Blue)?

Comment: @Robin 20 logos is probably tractable with a brute-force TSP solver, with some simple optimizations.  What's your implementation environment?

Comment: @Robin: About selecting the starting point - if a single run finishes in a reasonable time, checking all the possible starting points and selecting the best one wouldn't be a big problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the [travelling salesman problem (TSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Let me explain.

First, consider an example where you have a map with four cities `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. (I use 4 in the example but it has nothing to do with the number of colors). You want to find a route between the cities so you (1) visit each city only once and (2) the route is the shortest possible. `[D,C,A,B]` might be shorter that `[B,A,D,C]` and you want the shortest one.

Now, instead of the cities you have four logos. You want to find such an ordering of the logos, that yields a minimum cost in terms of color mixing. If you imagine that each of your logos is a point (city), and the distance between the logos is the "cost" of switching between one color set to the other, then you need to find the shortest "route" between the points. Once you have this shortest route, it tells you how you should order the logos. The "distance" between two logos L1 and L2 can be defined, for example, as a number of colors in L2 that are not in L1.

TSP it is a well known algorithmic problem. And it is hard (actually, [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard)).
If your input is small you can find the best solution. In case of 4 logos, you have 24 posible combinations. For 10 logos, you have 3.6 million combinations and for 20 logos you get 2432902008176640000 combinations (how to read that?). So for inputs larger than 10-15 you need to use some heuristic that finds an approximate solution, which I am sure is enough for you.

What I would do is that I would create a graph of costs of color mixing and feed it to some [TSP solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Free_software_for_solving_TSP)

**EDIT**:

- Clarification. Not each logo is a separate point, but each *set of colours in a logo* is a point. That is: if you have two logos that have the same set of colours, you consider them as a single point because they will be printed together. Logos with *red, blue, black* are on point and logos with *red, green* are another point.
- It's rather [Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) than TSP (you don't need to end with the same color set as at the beginning), but it doesn't change much
- If there might be no matches in your logos, then first split your logos into disjoint groups that have no matches between them and later consider each group separately. If  there are no matches between any of your logos, then you cannot do much :)
- Practically, I would use python and maybe [networkx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkX) library to model your problem as graph, and later I would pass it to some TSP solver. Just format the input and make some other program do all the dirty work.

Comment: Not every permutational optimization problem is equivalent to the TSP.  That's because there are many, *many* different kinds of constraints that can be laid on the TSP that can make it less than NP-Hard, and thus effectively *not* the TSP.  The problem stated here for instance, does not have unconstrained real-valued costs (distances) between its Travel Points, but rather has a k-binary summed cost structure: travel cost equals the sum of the number of colors different between the two logos. I do not know if that makes it less than NP-Hard, but that is effectively the question being asked.

Comment: Can you explain "k-binary summed cost structure"?

Comment: K is the number of different possible colors.  In TSP terms, the geometry of the "space" occupied by the Logos is equivalent to a k-dimensional binary space (ie., only 0 or 1) like the corners of a k-dimensional cube.  Each logo occupies one of those corners (though only the ones with four or less dimensions equal to 1, the other dimensions are zero for that Logo).  The "cost" of going from one logo to another is equal to the number or edges that have to be traversed to move through adjacent corners until you reached the next logo's corner of the hyper-cube.

Comment: My point being: that's a lot of constraints away from the unconstrained-TSP, so it may well be less than NP-Hard.

Comment: A detail: probably going from color set *red,green,black* to *red,green* will have cost 0 (no need to mix paint), and going in opposite direction would have cost of 1 (need to mix).

Comment: Still, it is an interesting problem to bite. Hope that OP will give some more examples and details.

Comment: Yes, I missed that wrinkle.  Going from 1 to 0 on a dimension is probably free.

Comment: As mentioned by dstromberg, genetic algorithms might be a good approach here even if solving the problem explicitly *is* NP hard.

Comment: If we are here, then Simulated Annealing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing is also worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

For a reasonable amount of logos and colors, an easy way would be a *brute-force* approach in which you go through all the combinations and increase a counter each time mixing is required. After that, you sort combinations by that counter and choose the one with the lowest value.

Pseudocode

```
foreach combination
    foreach print
        foreeach color 
            if not previous_print.contains(color)
                cost++

order combination by cost (ascending)
```

You didn't mention if you are using (or are about to) any kind of tool (spreadsheet, programming language, ...) in which you intended perform this sort.

Edit:

Here's a quick implementation in VB.NET. Note that the code is intentionally left long as to make it easier to read and understand.

```
Private Sub GoGoGo()
    ' Adds some logos 
    ' This is where you add them from the database or text file or wherever
    Dim logos() =
    {
        New String() {"Black", "Magenta", "Orange"},
        New String() {"Red", "Green", "Blue"},
        New String() {"Orange", "Violet", "Pink"},
        New String() {"Blue", "Yellow", "Pink"}
    }

    ' Used to store the best combination
    Dim minimumPermutation
    Dim minimumCost = Integer.MaxValue

    ' Calculate all permutations of the logos
    Dim permutations = GetPermutations(logos)

    ' For each permutation
    For i As Integer = 0 To permutations.Count() - 1
        Dim permutation = permutations(i)
        Dim cost = 0

        ' For each logo in permutation
        For j As Integer = 0 To permutation.Count() - 1
            Dim logo = permutation(j)

            ' Check whether the previous logo contains one or more colors of this logo
            For Each color In logo
                If (j > 0) Then
                    If Not permutation(j - 1).Contains(color) Then
                        cost += 1
                    End If
                Else
                    cost += 1
                End If
            Next
        Next

        ' Save the best permutation
        If (i = 0 Or cost < minimumCost) Then
            minimumCost = cost
            minimumPermutation = permutation.Clone()
        End If
    Next

    ' Output the best permutation
    For Each logo In minimumPermutation
        Console.Write(logo(0) + " " + logo(1) + " " + logo(2))
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Iterator Function GetPermutations(Of T)(values As T(), Optional fromInd As Integer = 0) As IEnumerable(Of T())
    If fromInd + 1 = values.Length Then
        Yield values
    Else
        For Each v In GetPermutations(values, fromInd + 1)
            Yield v
        Next

        For i = fromInd + 1 To values.Length - 1
            SwapValues(values, fromInd, i)
            For Each v In GetPermutations(values, fromInd + 1)
                Yield v
            Next
            SwapValues(values, fromInd, i)
        Next
    End If
End Function

Private Shared Sub SwapValues(Of T)(values As T(), pos1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer)
    If pos1 <> pos2 Then
        Dim tmp As T = values(pos1)
        values(pos1) = values(pos2)
        values(pos2) = tmp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am planning on writing the code in either VB.NET or SQL Server depending on what needs to be done. This solution looks plausible since we are only dealing with 20 logos or so. The only problem is selecting the correct first logo.

Comment: `foreach combination` - do you mean all possible ordering of labels?

Comment: I added an example in VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a Genetic Algorithm would be good for this.  If you have a lot of logos, a brute force solution could take quite a while, and greedy is unlikely to produce good results.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm

Comment: +1 because genetic algorithms *are* a good approach to the Travelling Salesman Problem.